# Solr query: near related results is empty

Tags: solr

I'm lanching this query request to my solr (`q=Igualada` and `defType=dismax`):

```
$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/arxius/select?defType=dismax&q=Igualada
```

And I'm getting a response with several documents:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":5,
    "params":{
      "q":"Igualada",
      "defType":"dismax",
      "_":"1603718924572"}},
  "response":{"numFound":654,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "title_txt_ca":"Igualada, clavegueram ciutat Igualada, projecte general i plànols",
        "id":"2e8b90b6-ed9b-4d32-9494-877b91417df3",
        "_version_":1681621123182100492,
        "code_l_ns":11645},
      {...
```

Nevertheless, I've also tried to launch a query searching `"Igualda"`, instead of `"Igualada"` (`q=Igualda`), but then I'm getting no results:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"Igualda",
      "defType":"dismax",
      "_":"1603718924572"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  }
}
```

I was expecting to get some near related results...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you expect to get some results that are close? That won't happen by itself, you either have to use a analysis chain that makes changes so those are similar (for example phonetic search), or you have to use a fuzzy query (`term~<edit distance>` - for example `term~2`). Look at the spell checking component to get "did you mean" functionality, or the suggester to get typing suggestions while typing.

Comment: Is there any way to get a fuzzy search without using `~`? I though `dismax` is for that...

Comment: No, dismax is for allowing for more natural search queries across multiple fields and with a more natural input (i.e. no field names, less special syntax etc.) and uses the maximum of disjunct queries for scoring (which is where the name comes from). If you don't want to use the fuzzy operator, you'll have to this in your analysis chain, such as through phonetic filters or other, similar filters that modify your content. Only exact matches between query and indexed tokens will generate hits, so both have to be modified in a way to give the same result for similar input. Phonetic is one way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a `text_ca` (Catalan) with the default configuration in Solr what you are getting would be the expected behavior.

If you index "Igualda" as a `text_ca` field in the Solr [Analysis Screen](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/analysis-screen.html) you'll see that it indexes it as "iguald".

If you index "Igualada" as a `text_ca` field you'll see that indexes it as "igual". Hence there is no match (iguald != igual).

The `text_ca` field uses the Solr [SnowballPorterFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/filter-descriptions.html#snowball-porter-stemmer-filter) with language Catalan. I am not sure if there are any settings that you could tweak there to get these results to match.